# Run mysql-workbench remotely, no proxy/or tunnel

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, rds, x11

We are on AWS, with a MySql RDS.  The RDS is set up so that only clients that are on the VPC can access it. (Just being VPN'd in is not good enough)

So I assume that I could set up a tunnel,proxy, etc...  But the questions was raised if it were possible to have mysql-workbench running in the cloud, on the VPC,  and do some sort of x-windows (x11) type thing locally on my laptop?

I am running ubuntu, but others have a Mac.

Any ideas how this might be achieved?

**UPDATE**

So they want to try x11 and see how the responsiveness is.  I know this is too general, but does someone have a good starting point for me?

Comment: so go across the VPC? - for all intents and purposes it's on your LAN

Comment: why not use http://www.phpmyadmin.net/ instead?

Comment: probably because he's using workbench, do you understand the difference between a web server and database server?

Comment: While theoretically possible, it's pretty much a terrible idea, because it will be sluggish and unresponsive.  If you have the connectivity necessary for this, then you have the connectivity necessary to use a simple ssh tunnel... which is not that difficult.

Comment: Create a tiny EC2 instance for tunneling is simple. Setup x-env in EC2 also introduce security issues. And running workbench need a better EC2  instance.